# Is there a command to jump Nth line from current line?

Tags: vim

e.g. jump to 4000 line when I on 3000 line.
maybe some command like

```
:goto next 1000G
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 3 ways to go directly to line 4000:

```
:4000
```

---

```
4000G
```

---

```
4000gg
```

Or you can jump down 1000 lines like this:

```
1000j
```

Credit to [Lieven Keersmaekers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52598/lieven-keersmaekers), you can also jump down like so:

```
:+1000
```

Comment: another way: `:+1000`